# Can you store a clicked img as a variable?

Tags: javascript

For my website I make the visitor choose between two different images. Is it possible to store the image that they chose as a variable?  I then need to use that variable in an if conditional. Also is it possible to name each image as if it were a class?

Thanks!
Jenise

Comment: This is certainly possible. Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use Javascript + jQuery:

```
var my_images = [];

$('img').click(function(){

    my_images.push(this);

});
```

This will store the HTML DOM elements in an array for use later.

Highly recommend getting to grips with Javascript and then using jQuery (a Javascript library) for anything DOM related.

http://jquery.com/